# GAE authenticate to a 3rd party site

Tags: security, google-app-engine, authentication, passwords

I need to authenticate securely to a third party site for a SSL REST api call. I have the API call part working but I want to save the third party credentials in my app engine datastore, or maybe somewhere else? I have no idea how im supposed to do this.

The SSL call looks like:

```
credentials = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password))[:-1]
request     = urllib2.Request(accounts_url)
request.add_header("User-Agent", user_agent)
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % credentials)

stream   = urllib2.urlopen(request)
response = stream.read()
stream.close()
```

which means my app unfortunately needs to know the plaintext password. It doesn't make sense to me to AES encrypt it (not a hash--reversible) because the decryption key would need to be known by my app also so if my app is compromised no real security over storing plaintext was added.

Comment: What does "Hope for the best" mean? What scenarios/problems are you worried about/wanting to prevent?

Comment: I believe he is worried that if someone were to get access to his datastore, they would get access to the third party site as well.

Comment: All I know is that security scares me shitless and I have no idea what I need to be worried about. what if my app has a bug which spills the credentials? googling 'third party authentication' and other such searches aren't turning up anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most secure strategy here is to punt to the client.  Use GAE to serve as a proxy for what would otherwise be a cross domain request from the client.  I'm assuming the third party host has some sort of token or session cookie that you could intercept on the way back.

**Storing plain text passwords is scary.**